# How to sort 2 groups of data in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have topics collection where I store topics like this:

```
{
    "headline" : "Quis sint et aut non quos.",
    "announce" : "Rerum suscipit omnis qui ducimus.",
    "body" : "<p>Ad amet et. Sed quod porro maxime doloribus.</p>",
    "published_at" : ISODate("2015-02-20T21:24:52.000Z"),
    "rubrics" : [ 
        {
            "slug" : "news",
            "title" : "News"
        }
    ],
    "subrubrics" : [ 
        {
            "slug" : "ratings",
            "title" : "Ratings"
        }
    ],
    "lists" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "News",
            "slug" : "news",
            "position": 12
        }
    ]
}
```

And my goal is to get topics sorted as follows:

1. First part: all topics with `lists.slug = "A"` sorted by `lists.position`
2. Second part: **goes after first**, all topics with `rubrics.slug or subrubrics.slug = "A"` sorted by `published_at`

Expected output:

```
[
  /* First part */
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 1 } ]},
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 2 } ]},
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 3 } ]},
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 4 } ]},
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 5 } ]},
  {"lists": [ { "title": "News", "slug": "news", "position": 6 } ]},
  /* Second part */
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-19T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-18T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-17T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-16T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-15T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
  {"published_at": ISODate("2015-02-13T00:00:00.000Z"), "rubrics": [ { "title": "News Rubric", "slug": "news" } ]},
]
```

*Note that I don't now if I'll get slug for rubric or subrubric in advance.*

I'm not very experienced in MongoDB aggregation framework and I only was able to write something like this, which does only the first part (MongoID):

```
projection = {
    _id: 0,
    lists: 1,
}
slug = 'news'
collection.aggregate(
    {'$project' => projection},
    {'$unwind' => '$lists'},
    {'$match' => {'lists.slug' => slug}},
    {'$sort' => {'lists.position' => 1}}
)
```

How can I do both parts in one query? Would it be effective? Is it possible to do this through Mongoid?

Comment: Can you post your expected output here.

Comment: @yogesh, done that in question

Comment: `lists` is an array. How would you want to sort a document that has two `lists.position` values 1 and 12 relative to another that has `lists.position` values of 4 and 8? Assume both documents have a value `lists.slug = "A"`.

Comment: `lists` array can't have objects with the same slug, for sure. I sort documents with different `lists.position` values using `unwind` operator as written above.

Comment: Have a deep look at the expected output. That would need two projections. While querying for different sets of criteria in one query is easily possible using a logical or, the output of a query can have only one projection.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, can you please provide query as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the [documentation for mongodb for sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and this looks like its really simple to do

there is a **$sort** method  and this method *Sorts all input documents and returns them to the pipeline in sorted order.*

**example**

```
{ $sort: { <field1>: <sort order>, <field2>: <sort order> ... } }
```

now the  take 1 of 2 possibles values

- 1 to specify ascending order.
- -1 to specify descending order.

your example

```
collection.aggregate(
    {'$project' => projection},
    {'$unwind' => '$lists'},
    {'$match' => {'lists.slug' => slug}},
    {'$sort' => {'lists.position' => 1, 'lists.slug' => -1}}
)
```

look at the line `{'$sort' => {'lists.position' => 1, 'lists.slug' => -1}}`

Please read more about how to sort in the mongodb manual http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: That doesn't cover the second part. In the second part I need to get all items, which are not in the current list and sort them by published date.